# LD_PRELOAD can not intercept syscalls, but only libcalls?

Tags: c, system-calls, ld-preload, systrace

My code works well with `malloc`, but not with `mmap`. The code is below:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  int * p = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
  printf("in main(): value p = %d\n", *p);
  free(p);
}
```

preload.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <time.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void *(*orig_malloc)(size_t size);
void *malloc(size_t size){
  printf("  Hooked(preload)! malloc:size:%lu\n", size);
  return orig_malloc(size);
}

void * (*orig_mmap)(void *start, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset);
void * mmap(void *start, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset){
  printf("  Hooked(preload)! mmap:start:%p, length:%lu, prot:%d, flags:%p, fd:%p, offset:%d\n", start, length, prot, flags, fd, offset);
  return orig_mmap(start, length, prot, flags, fd, offset);
}

void
_init(void)
{
  printf("Loading hack.\n");
  orig_malloc = (void* (*)(size_t)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
  orig_mmap = (void* (*)(void*, size_t, int, int, int, off_t)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "mmap");
}
```

to compile it

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -DPIC -c preload.c
ld -shared -o preload.so preload.o -ldl
gcc main.c
```

to run it with `LD_PRELOAD`

```
LD_PRELOAD=./preload.so ./a.out
```

to run it with strace

```
strace ./a.out 2>&1 | view -
```

the printout from `LD_PRELOAD` does not hook calls to `mmap`, but only calls to `malloc`. Meanwhile, when running with `strace`, the printout does show `mmap` is called multiple times.

This result baffles me; assuming `mmap` is indeed called by `main.c` (I guess through `malloc`), how come `preload.c` can not intercept `mmap`?

PS: My platform is Ubuntu 14.04 with Linux kernel 3.13

PS2: By syscall, I mean the syscall wrapper in libc (not sure if this makes a difference to the question though)..

Comment: to people looking _how_ to inject failures or fake success in syscalls: look for `strace` `-e inject` option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mmap is a syscall, malloc is not.

Since syscalls are essential for the functioning of a program, they must work before ld.so actually springs into action, they are reside in a section that gets loaded before everything else; it may be linked dynamically, but that mapping *(of that particular "virtual" dynamic object)* is done by the kernel itself. Looong before ld.so actually gets to work.

Comment: What I mean by syscall is really syscall wrapper in libc.. in this sense, can `LD_PRELOAD` capture syscall wrapper? (I suppose syscall wrapper is called after ld.so)

Comment: @Richard: No, the syscall wrapper in libc is bound to the PLT stub very early. So early that LD_PRELOAD is not able to take effect.

Comment: @Richard: See this article on how the whole PLT/GOT thing works out: https://www.technovelty.org/linux/plt-and-got-the-key-to-code-sharing-and-dynamic-libraries.html

Comment: What you are wrapping here is not the tiny syscall wrapper automatically linked (which isn't even present in an actual file), but the `mmap()` function in your libc.

Comment: "No, the syscall wrapper in libc is bound to the PLT stub very early" - this is wrong. Intra-libc mmap calls are not done through PLT and that's why they can't be intercepted. On the contrary, mmap calls in other libraries and in executable are done through PLT and can be interposed just as any other API. "dynamic linking is executed by the kernel itself" - wrong too, kernel does not do _any_ dynamic linking itself.

Comment: @yugr: I was not talking about dynamic linking of arbitrary libraries, but refering to the linkage of that special piece of code that implements syscall entry/exit: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html notably this part: *The "vDSO" (virtual dynamic shared object) is a small shared library that __the kernel automatically maps__ into the address space of all user-space applications.* An in-depth explanation of what it does and how it works can be found here: http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/08/linux-gate/

Comment: Well, kernel maps vDSO (it also maps executable and `ld.so`) but does not do any linkage for it. _All_ dynamic linking, even for vDSO, is done in `ld.so`, not in kernel.

Comment: @yugr: Eh, yes. I think I meant mapping when I wrote it (corrected it). And yes, it's `ld.so` (or whatever is specified as interpreter) that does the actual linking, which is why I mentioned that, too. Hmm, I think deleting that answer would be the best course of action, but SO won't allow it. Maybe suggest a few edits?

Comment: @traducerad: You'd have to work some [`ptrace(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) magic for that: Attach ptrace to process (set ptrace flags to execve the target process in a stopped state, then attach), with `PTRACE_SYSCALL` and everytime the process stops, manipulate the call stack to modify the syscall. Yes, I know, that's not pretty straightforward, but the intended way to do this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 7):

The `mmap` calls printed by `strace` are glibc-internal.
It's impossible to intercept the glibc-internal calls to `mmap` with `LD_PRELOAD`:

`mmap` is not in the `.plt`-section of `/lib64/libc.so.6` but is called directly from glibc and therefore `LD_PRELOAD` can't intercept glibc's calls to `mmap`.

```
$ objdump -j .plt -d /lib64/libc.so.6 

/lib64/libc.so.6:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .plt:

000000000001f400 <*ABS*+0x8e3fb@plt-0x10>:
   1f400:   ff 35 02 ac 39 00       pushq  0x39ac02(%rip)        # 3ba008 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x8>
   1f406:   ff 25 04 ac 39 00       jmpq   *0x39ac04(%rip)        # 3ba010 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x10>
   1f40c:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)

000000000001f410 <*ABS*+0x8e3fb@plt>:
   1f410:   ff 25 02 ac 39 00       jmpq   *0x39ac02(%rip)        # 3ba018 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x18>
   1f416:   68 0b 00 00 00          pushq  $0xb
   1f41b:   e9 e0 ff ff ff          jmpq   1f400 <data.8467+0x1f390>

000000000001f420 <*ABS*+0xb8c10@plt>:
   1f420:   ff 25 fa ab 39 00       jmpq   *0x39abfa(%rip)        # 3ba020 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x20>
   1f426:   68 0a 00 00 00          pushq  $0xa
   1f42b:   e9 d0 ff ff ff          jmpq   1f400 <data.8467+0x1f390>

000000000001f430 <realloc@plt>:
   1f430:   ff 25 f2 ab 39 00       jmpq   *0x39abf2(%rip)        # 3ba028 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x28>
   1f436:   68 00 00 00 00          pushq  $0x0
   1f43b:   e9 c0 ff ff ff          jmpq   1f400 <data.8467+0x1f390>

000000000001f440 <malloc@plt>:
   1f440:   ff 25 ea ab 39 00       jmpq   *0x39abea(%rip)        # 3ba030 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x30>
   1f446:   68 01 00 00 00          pushq  $0x1
   1f44b:   e9 b0 ff ff ff          jmpq   1f400 <data.8467+0x1f390>

000000000001f450 <__tls_get_addr@plt>:
   1f450:   ff 25 e2 ab 39 00       jmpq   *0x39abe2(%rip)        # 3ba038 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x38>
   1f456:   68 02 00 00 00          pushq  $0x2
   1f45b:   e9 a0 ff ff ff          jmpq   1f400 <data.8467+0x1f390>

000000000001f460 <memalign@plt>:
   1f460:   ff 25 da ab 39 00       jmpq   *0x39abda(%rip)        # 3ba040 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x40>
   1f466:   68 03 00 00 00          pushq  $0x3
   1f46b:   e9 90 ff ff ff          jmpq   1f400 <data.8467+0x1f390>

000000000001f470 <*ABS*+0x90f60@plt>:
   1f470:   ff 25 d2 ab 39 00       jmpq   *0x39abd2(%rip)        # 3ba048 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x48>
   1f476:   68 09 00 00 00          pushq  $0x9
   1f47b:   e9 80 ff ff ff          jmpq   1f400 <data.8467+0x1f390>

000000000001f480 <_dl_find_dso_for_object@plt>:
   1f480:   ff 25 ca ab 39 00       jmpq   *0x39abca(%rip)        # 3ba050 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x50>
   1f486:   68 04 00 00 00          pushq  $0x4
   1f48b:   e9 70 ff ff ff          jmpq   1f400 <data.8467+0x1f390>

000000000001f490 <calloc@plt>:
   1f490:   ff 25 c2 ab 39 00       jmpq   *0x39abc2(%rip)        # 3ba058 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x58>
   1f496:   68 05 00 00 00          pushq  $0x5
   1f49b:   e9 60 ff ff ff          jmpq   1f400 <data.8467+0x1f390>

000000000001f4a0 <free@plt>:
   1f4a0:   ff 25 ba ab 39 00       jmpq   *0x39abba(%rip)        # 3ba060 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x60>
   1f4a6:   68 06 00 00 00          pushq  $0x6
   1f4ab:   e9 50 ff ff ff          jmpq   1f400 <data.8467+0x1f390>

000000000001f4b0 <*ABS*+0xb8bc0@plt>:
   1f4b0:   ff 25 b2 ab 39 00       jmpq   *0x39abb2(%rip)        # 3ba068 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x68>
   1f4b6:   68 08 00 00 00          pushq  $0x8
   1f4bb:   e9 40 ff ff ff          jmpq   1f400 <data.8467+0x1f390>

000000000001f4c0 <*ABS*+0x8ec70@plt>:
   1f4c0:   ff 25 aa ab 39 00       jmpq   *0x39abaa(%rip)        # 3ba070 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x70>
   1f4c6:   68 07 00 00 00          pushq  $0x7
   1f4cb:   e9 30 ff ff ff          jmpq   1f400 <data.8467+0x1f390>
[m@localhost ~]$
```

Calls to `mmap` in glibc don't call it via a `.plt` entry but directly, it's impossible to intercept these calls:

```
$ objdump -d /lib64/libc.so.6 | grep mmap
[...]
   81628:   e8 83 ad 07 00          callq  fc3b0 <mmap>
   8177c:   e8 2f ac 07 00          callq  fc3b0 <mmap>
00000000000fc3b0 <mmap>:
   fc3c0:   73 01                   jae    fc3c3 <mmap+0x13>
  13a267:   e8 44 21 fc ff          callq  fc3b0 <mmap>
$
```

```
00000000000fc3b0 <mmap>:
   fc3b0:   49 89 ca                mov    %rcx,%r10
   fc3b3:   b8 09 00 00 00          mov    $0x9,%eax
   fc3b8:   0f 05                   syscall 
   fc3ba:   48 3d 01 f0 ff ff       cmp    $0xfffffffffffff001,%rax
   fc3c0:   73 01                   jae    fc3c3 <mmap+0x13>
   fc3c2:   c3                      retq   
   fc3c3:   48 8b 0d 96 da 2b 00    mov    0x2bda96(%rip),%rcx        # 3b9e60 <_DYNAMIC+0x2e0>
   fc3ca:   f7 d8                   neg    %eax
   fc3cc:   64 89 01                mov    %eax,%fs:(%rcx)
   fc3cf:   48 83 c8 ff             or     $0xffffffffffffffff,%rax
   fc3d3:   c3                      retq   
   fc3d4:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   fc3db:   00 00 00 
   fc3de:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
```

Comment: Sorry, but sure the libc `mmap()` can be hooked that way! Just use the OP's code and a tiny test program calling `mmap()` ... result is here: "Hooked(preload)! mmap:start:(nil), length:20, prot:3, flags:0x22, fd:0xffffffff, offset:0"

Comment: Yes, but not glibc's calls to its `mmap` @FelixPalmen

Comment: so what lib defines it? It's definitely intercepted and the `LD_PRELOAD` "trick" can only intercept calls to libraries linked by `ld.so` [**edit** I think you refer to library-internal calls ... right?]

Comment: @FelixPalmen "I think you refer to library-internal calls ... right?" Yes.

Comment: capturing glibc-internal calls `mmap` is impossible with `LD_PRELOAD`, but they are captured by `strace`.. wondering how that is done?

Comment: @Richard [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6672788) I found an answer how strace works.

Comment: thx.. though, strace is based on ptrace, which will switch into kernel space at runtime... which is something I want to avoid...

Answer (score 3):

The title to your question is actually the answer.

> assuming mmap is indeed called by main.c (I guess through malloc)

So your main.c doesn't call the *library function* `mmap()`? Of course you can't intercept syscalls this way, how would you do it? Some architectures have a `syscall` CPU instruction, some use a special interrupt ... there are a lot of ways, but it's in any case completely different from C calling conventions. The kernel is not somehow *linked* to your binary but takes control (with some hardware assistence) when your userspace process does something ... "special".

If you want to know how to intercept syscalls, this is of course very platform specific, but I would advise you to just take a look in the source of the `strace` utility. You will never see an `malloc()` in strace, because this is not a syscall, `malloc()` uses the `mmap` syscall.

On the other hand, if you preload your lib to a binary that actually calls the libc `mmap()` function, it will work as expected.

In a nutshell: libc `mmap()` is a user-friendly wrapper around the `mmap` syscall and with the following main:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main()
{
    void *test = mmap(0, 20, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS,
        -1, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

> Loading hack.
>    Hooked(preload)! mmap:start:(nil), length:20, prot:3, flags:0x22,
>   fd:0xffffffff, offset:0

Comment: I am targeting on `x86_64` only; seems the `syscall` instruction scheme is used. wondering if syscall interception can be done by simply hooking with all `syscall` instructions in a binary...

Comment: I don't think so ... `syscall` is on the one hand a CPU instruction (you can't hook those) and on the other hand a minimal wrapper in `glibc` allowing programs to call any syscall using C calling conventions. The latter can be hooked using LD_PRELOAD.

Comment: I believe it is doable by binary rewriting technique though

Comment: Well yes, ideally if it `syscall` instructions can be replaced with an instruction of the same length just calling some own subroutine .. but i guess it's a one-word instruction taking no data? Ah well, I never learned x86 instruction set, so I'm out ;)

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question. The author clearly specified that he's interested in syscall wrapper, not syscall itself.

Comment: @yugr the "PS" in the question was added after my answer, but it doesn't even matter; when libc calls its own functions, there's no dynamic symbol involved.

Comment: I think this answer is out of date. The title doesn't match what the answer claims. And the answer recommends to use strace, but in the question the user explained that he already did use strace.

Answer (score 0):

The [syscall_intercept](https://github.com/pmem/syscall_intercept) library does some binary rewriting tricks to intercept syscalls coming from libc. You can `LD_PRELOAD` your interception logic written using this library and it will intercept the syscalls; you can choose to handle them and/or pass them on to the kernel.